# What is the *.def file at c++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I compile old c++ project with visual studio 2013.

I get error:

```
LNK114:cannot open file 'Banana.def' at my Banana project.
```

What is it? And how to fix it?

P.S. i am new at c++ on visual studio.

Yes, i building DLL.

Comment: What are you building (exe or dll) and how (makefile or project file) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .def file is normally not used for building an exe. Extract from [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28d6s79h.aspx) documentation : 
*A .def file is most useful when building a DLL. Because there are linker options that can be used instead of module-definition statements, .def files are generally not necessary. You can also use __declspec(dllexport) as a way to specify exported functions ... If you are building an .exe file that has no exports, using a .def file will make your output file larger and slower loading.*

Unless you are building a DLL, `banana.def` should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

It's a **module definition** file, probably specifying the exports of a DLL library.

You're missing the file, or it's not accessible.